# Cutting and pasting nodes in a TreeView control?

Tags: vb6, treeview, paste

I'm looking to implement a cut and paste method to replace drag and drop in a `TreeView` control. Drag and drop no longer works in the TreeView, and I believe cut and paste will be easier for the people using it. In this TreeView, I will be working with cutting only the child nodes. This object has only parent and child nodes (parent being dates and child nodes being purchase orders.) I'm not sure if there is a `cut` property and/or `paste` property to use with `treeview1.node.selected` or whatever I need to use.

Comment: its doubtful it would work that way.  I dont recall how the old VB6 critter worked but it may be as simple as changing the parent(?).  If not, get a reference to the cuttee, remove it, then add it to the new parent.

Comment: would it be better to add a right click context menu? im just looking for an alternative to drag and drop.

Comment: it **may** be easier - Cut would be the first step (create a ref and remove from tree; Paste would be adding it to the new parent.  There is a small risk of loosing the node, if they cut without pasting, or corruption (?) if they paste it later after others have been added, or try to paste it to a child.  You'd have to add code to validate the destination maybe.

Comment: so for cutting maybe make a storage location for the copied node like `dim copynode as node` and upon clicking cut it copies the selected node to `copynode`. then remove the selected node. so the node is stored in the copynode slot. then on the paste command it could paste it to the selected node as long as the selected node has children. thats my thought process so far but im not sure how to check if the node has children when im pasting to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... upon clicking cut it copies the selected node to `copynode`. then remove the selected node.
>   so the node is stored in the `copynode` slot

This won't work as `copynode` is a *reference* to the thing you just removed (destroyed) so after removal `copynode` will point to `Nothing`.

Instead; when a cut event occurs store the key features of the cut node (text, key, icon index etc.) in to a module level user defined type (or delimited string/class/series of variables) and remove the node. You can then use this data as the basis to construct a new node when a paste event is raised.

(The cut/paste events are not bound to the windows clipboard, rather thay are your own inventions based upon a context menu/detection of ctrl+X/V)

> im not sure how to check if the node has children when im pasting to it

```
if tv.SelectedItem.Children > 0 then
   ... got child nodes
```

Comment: while all this makes sense, through playing around with code in a practice treeview i haven't been able to register the ctrl+x key event (it doesnt do anything in the keydown sub). I'm also having trouble with removing the old node upon cutting it. `treeview1.nodes.remove` doesn't seem to do anything regardless of what i put after it.

Comment: To remove the selected item; `tvw.Nodes.Remove tvw.SelectedItem.Index`

Comment: In the tv's `KeyDown` event: `If KeyCode = vbKeyX And (Shift And vbCtrlMask) Then msgbox "cut"`